# Map.getValue() returns a List a certain time, an Object another time

Tags: java, list, dictionary, getvalue

I have the following code:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Something>> somethingByString : somethingsByString.entrySet()) {
    methodThatTakesAListOfSomething(somethingByString.getValue());
}
```

I try to change the code with this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Something>> somethingByString : somethingsByString.entrySet()) {
    for(Something something : somethingsByString.getValue()) {
        methodThatTakesAListOfSomething(something);
}
```

The compiler then says that my method can't take `Something` as an argument, it requires `List<Something>`.

Why does `somethingsByString.getValue()` returns `List<Something>` in the first case, and `Something` in the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`somethingsByString.getValue()` returns a `List<Something>` in both cases.

However, in the second case you are iterating over the elements of that `List<Something>` (using an enhanced for loop) and trying to pass a single `Something` instance to `methodThatTakesAListOfSomething`. This doesn't work, since that method required a `List<Something>`.

If you want to process each `Something` instance in a separate method call, you should change `methodThatTakesAListOfSomething` to take a single `Something` instance, or create a new method that takes a single `Something`:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Something>> somethingByString : somethingsByString.entrySet()) {
    for(Something something : somethingsByString.getValue()) {
        methodThatTakesSomething(something);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is simply because in the second case you're using a nested `foreach` loop meaning you're iterating over the entries with the first `foreach` loop and then the second loop iterates over the elements of the list.

Thus giving the compilation error as a method declared like  `methodThatTakesAListOfSomething(List<Something> input)`  cannot take an input of type `Something`.

*These are two completely different types*.

Rather, to overcome the issue if your method expects a type `Something` instead of a `List<Something>`then declare the method to have a parameter of `methodThatTakesAListOfSomething(Something input)` else if the method should take a `List<Something>` then declare the method as `methodThatTakesAListOfSomething(List<Something> input)`.

Lastly, but not least only use a nested `foreach` loop when you need to access `Something` and use a single `foreach` loop when you want to access `List<Something>`.